# Ruby Module Include Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a CommonFunctions Module inside the lib/ folder. I have a Question Model, which includes the CommonFunctions module. Now I am trying to access the favorite function of the CommonFunctions like Question.favorite. But I am getting NoMethodError. I have included the code. Can anyone please tell me where I am doing the mistake

**Error**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `favorite' for Class:0x00000100e11508
```

**Inside lib/CommonFunctions.rb**

```
module CommonFunctions
  def favorite(object_id)
  end
end
```

**Inside app/models/Question.rb**

```
require 'lib/CommonFunctions.rb'
class Question
  extend CommonFunctions
end
```

**I am executing the following code from the script/console**

```
   Question.favorite(1)
```

Thanks

---

This was a duplicate of [How do I properly include a module and call module functions from my Rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355619/how-do-i-properly-include-a-module-and-call-module-functions-from-my-rails-model)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. Make sure you have the current version of the classes loaded in the console (try `reload!`).

As a sidenote: if you rename CommonFunctions.rb to common_functions.rb, it will be autoloaded by rails and you don't need the require.

Answer (score 1):

The module method is an instance method when you want it to be a class method. Use the code below instead

```
module CommonFunctions   
  def self.favorite(object_id)   
  end 
end
```

Using the word "self" defines the method as a class method (or static)